# Contour line parameters in seaborn kde plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to figure out a way to adjust the width and color of the contour lines in the seaborn plot below:

[image]

I would like them all to be just thin black lines, although I have no idea how to pass the parameters... Providing 'linewidth' does not seem to work...
The code:

```
g = sns.jointplot(x="s_zscore", y="p_zscore", data=scatter_all, kind="kde", space=0, stat_func=None, marginal_kws={"color":"black", "lw":0.5}, color="black", shade=False, n_levels=10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the arguments passed to the **contour** function using the **joint_kws** in the jointplot function.

Like this:

```
g = sns.jointplot(x="s_zscore", y="p_zscore", data=scatter_all, kind="kde", space=0, stat_func=None, marginal_kws={"color":"black", "lw":0.5}, joint_kws={"colors":"black","cmap":None, "linewidths":0.5}, shade=False, n_levels=10)
```

The only change I've made is the addition of:

```
joint_kws={"colors":"black","cmap":None, "linewidths":0.5}
```

Here's the output:

[image]